# Populating JTable with Map data

Tags: java, swing, loops, dictionary, jtable

I'm trying to populate a JTable with data from a map that contains Strings and floats.  Here is how I'm trying to do it, but I get the same data over and over.

```
private JTable buildTable(Map<String, Float> mapData){

   String columnNames[] = { "MyString", "MyFloat" };
   Object[][] data = new Object[mapData.size()][2];

   for(int i = 0; i < mapData.size(); i++){

      for(Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : mapData.entrySet()){

         data[i][0] = entry.getKey();
         data[i][1] = entry.getValue().getMyFloat();
         break;
      }
   }

   JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

   return table;
}
```

Comment: maybe there isn't reason to convert Map<> to JTable, implements AbstractTableModel with Map as source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop writes all key/value pairs to the same array indexes on each iteration of the outer loop. In fact, we only need one loop, not two. A separate counter to increment the indexes would help.

```
int i = 0;
for(Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : mapData.entrySet()) {

  data[i][0] = entry.getKey();
  data[i][1] = entry.getValue().getMyFloat();
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Bingo!  This was it!  Thanks so much!!